# Error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (state) inside render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

In my project I have a table from react material ui. I am getting an error while filling this table when I use data from state to fill the table. The error is `cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. The line where it occurs will be marked in the code snippet below.

Here is my code (the error is in the JSX render method):

```
class AllBooks extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          rows: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('component mounted!');

        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/all-books').then(allBooks => {
            console.log(allBooks.data);

            this.setState({
                rows: allBooks
            });
        });

    }

    onAddButtonClick = (row) => {
        console.log('onAddButton click!');
        console.log(row);
        //axios.post('http://localhost:8080/addBookToRentedBooks', { email: this.state.email, 
title: this.state.title, message: this.state.message }).then();
    }

    test = () => {
        console.log(this.state.rows.data);

        this.state.rows.data.map(row => console.log(row));
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div>
                <Grid container spacing={3}>
                    <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}></Grid>
                    
                    <Grid item xs={6} sm={6}>
                        <h1 style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>All Books</h1>
                        <br /><br />

                        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                            <Table  aria-label="simple table">
                                <TableHead>
                                    <TableRow>
                                        <TableCell >Title</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">Author</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">ISBN</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">Year</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="center">Actions</TableCell>
                                    </TableRow>
                                </TableHead>

                                <TableBody>
                                    {this.state.rows.data.map((row) => (
                                        <TableRow key={row.name}>
                                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                                {row.name}
                                            </TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">z</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">z</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">z</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="center">
                                        
                                                    <IconButton onClick={ () => this.onAddButtonClick(row) }>
                                                        <AddCircleOutlineIcon />
                                                    </IconButton>

                                            </TableCell>
                                        </TableRow>
                                ))}
                                </TableBody>
                            </Table>
                                    </TableContainer>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}><button onClick={this.test}>click me</button></Grid>
                </Grid>
            </div>
    )
    }

}
```

I wonder why `this.state.rows.data` is marked as undefined because I added a simple button - when i click this button, the `test` method gets called and prints out `this.state.rows` correctly.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks for every help!

Comment: Why is `rows` initialized as an empty array, if it's going to contain an object?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store the value of allBooks.data in rows instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because initial of state `rows` is `[]`. so when fetching data `this.state.rows.data` will be undefined.

You can use `optional chaining` to check it has value or not before using `map`:

```
this.state.rows.data?.map(...)
```